# How does one assign to window.onblur in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assign to window.onblur to call a KeyUp event handler so that when a user Alt + Tabs out of the browser with a key pressed, my website assumes it is no longer pressed (since, as far as I know, a website cannot detect key events outside the browser).  The problem I have is simple: I cannot even assign to window.onblur without TypeScript complaining about it!

TypeScript gives me: "Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FocusEvent'.  Property 'relatedTarget' is missing in type '() => void'." for the following code.

```
window.onblur(() => alert("Just Work!"));
```

and for:

```
window.onblur(function() { alert("Why don't you work?!"); });
```

I've even tried passing in a new `FocusEvent` which it seems to want but then I don't know what to give the FocusEvent!

```
window.onblur(new FocusEvent("What do you want?!", new FocusEventInit(() => CatManagerDashboardClass.handleCtrlKeyUp()));
```

The examples I've seen for JavaScript just equate to the first 2 examples I've given here; what am I doing wrong?  I just want TypeScript to 'compile' this code if it's valid code.

Comment: Are you meaning to assign rather than call? `window.onblur = () => alert("work");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do here in invoke the `onblur` function on the window object.

You'll want to add an event listener for the `onblur` event on the `window` using `addEventListener()`, which takes an event string, and a callback:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', () => alert('window blur'));
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I didn't see that!  I've been writing a lot of JQuery event handlers lately where the assignment call is: `.on("someEventName", () => alert("Handling event!")`; what I actually meant to write was `window.onblur = () => alert("Handling Window Blur")`.

Comment: You want to be careful overwriting the default `onblur` event, adding and removing new listeners is much safer

Comment: I didn't realize this overrode any default behaviour; `window.onblur` is `null` before I assign to it.

Comment: You're probably safe to use it for the most part, but if you start using frameworks which have default behaviour built in, it might produce weird ressults